# How to check if array is null and display not available if it's null

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, arraylist

Unfortunately my console is showing a 'The method '[]' was called on null.' error when I try to display a product page where the product doesn’t have the below array as an option in Firestore. Is there a way to check if the array has a null value and display ‘Product Personalisation Not Available' When the it’s not in Firestore. The following code works fine when the productPersonalisation list is available.

```
import 'package:fj_trade/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductPersonalisation extends StatefulWidget {


  final List productPersonalisation;
  final Function(String) onSelected;



  const ProductPersonalisation({Key key, this.productPersonalisation, this.onSelected}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductPersonalisationState createState() => _ProductPersonalisationState();
}

class _ProductPersonalisationState extends State<ProductPersonalisation> {

  int _selected = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [


        for(var  i=0; i < widget.productPersonalisation.length; i++)
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              widget.onSelected("${widget.productPersonalisation[i]}");
              setState(() {
                _selected = i;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
              height: 42,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _selected == i ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Constants.lightGrey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 6.0,
              ),
              child: Text("${widget.productPersonalisation[i]}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: _selected == i ? Colors.white : Colors.black87,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: widget.productPersonalisation == null //this will return true if it is null
    widget.productPersonalisation.isEmpty // will return true if there are no item in the List and the List is not Empty

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the element in the array is null

```
widget.onSelected("${widget.productPersonalisation[i] ?? 'Product Personalisation Not Available'}");
```

However before the loop, you should check that widget.productPersonalisation isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to access an index of a null list it will throw an exception.
Try this:

```
widget.onSelected(widget.productPersonalisation != null ? "${widget.productPersonalisation[i]}" : 'Product Personalisation Not Available');
```